# Java batch: How to programmatically determine which partition you are running?

Tags: java, concurrency, jsr352, jberet, jbatch

In a [JSR-352](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/batch-processing.html) batch I want to use partitioning. I can define the number of partitions via configuration or implement a [`PartitionMapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/api/partition/PartitionMapper.html) to do that.

Then, there are the [`JobContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/runtime/context/JobContext.html) and [`StepContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/runtime/context/StepContext.html) injectables to provide context information to my processing. However, there is no `PartitionContext` or the like which maintains and provides details about the *partition* I'm running in.

Hence the question:

**How do I tell each partitioned instance of a chunk *which* partition it is running in so that its `ItemReader` can read only those items which belong to that particular partition?**

If I don't do that, each partition would perform the same work on the same data instead of splitting up the input data set into `n` distinct partitions.

I know I can store some ID in the partition plan's properties which I can then use to set another property in the step's configuration like `<property name="partitionId" value="#{partitionPlan['partitionId']}" />`. But this seems overly complicated and fragile because I'd have to know the name of the property from the partition plan and must remember to always set another property to this value for each step.

Isn't there another, clean, standard way to provide partition information to steps?

Or, how else should I be splitting work by partitions and assign it to different `ItemReader` instances in the same partitioned chunk?

Update:

It appears that jberet has the [org.jberet.cdi.PartitionScoped](https://github.com/jberet/jberet-user-guide/blob/master/custom_cdi_scopes/README.md) CDI scope, but it's not part of the JSR standard.

Comment: Though it would have been reasonable to include this as a standard part of the 1.0 API spec it wasn't, so unfortunately you are left to construct your own convention/solution.   You're not missing anything.   The Batch API project is not active at the moment, but I believe this issue has been noted multiple times, and hopefully should be a strong candidate when the project resumes.

Comment: I think (hope) you'll agree that by editing and rephrasing the question title a bit, I better captured the key question here.

Comment: @ScottKurz Yes, thanks for the improvement :)

Comment: @ScottKurz I can't quite understand why this feature is not included anywhere in the standard. I believe that a) it's a feature which everybody using partitions will need and b) telling workers the total number of workers and their index is pretty much standard in parallel computing.

Comment: It's too late now.  Not EVERY app needs it though I'd support adding something like this.

Answer (score 1):

When defining a partition with either partition plan (XML), or partition mapper (programatical), include these information as partition properties, and then reference these partition properties within item reader/processor/writer properties.

This is the standard way to tell item reader and other batch artifacts what resource to handle, where to begin, and where to end.  This is not much different from non-partitioned chunk configuration, where you also need to configure the source and range of input data with batch properties.

For example, please [org.jberet.test.chunkPartitionFailComplete.xml](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/master/test-apps/chunkPartition/src/main/resources/META-INF/batch-jobs/org.jberet.test.chunkPartitionFailComplete.xml) from one of the jberet test apps.